# bash: alias: =: not found error upon opening Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

Every time I start Git Bash I'm running into this error (see screenshot)

I setup Sublime for Git Bash https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/sublime

Instead of using the `"C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"` extension I used `"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"` the first time around. It now works properly to open Sublime using 'subl' but I receive the bash: alias: =: not found everytime I open up Git Bash.[image]

Answer (score 4):

it seems that in your `~/.bashrc` you have two similar, but slightly different lines:

```
alias subl='C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'
alias subl = 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'
```

Look at the second one, it has spaces around an equal sign, so it is interpreted as not aliasing, but listing aliases for space separeted arguments `subl`, `=`, and `'C:\ ...'`.

Make sure you have only one appropriate line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Removed the two offending lines. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. You need to escape every white space with "\".

So change your commando to:

```
alias subl='C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, with OSX, I use:

```
alias edit="open -a '.../Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text' '$@'"
```

note: `...` is just for brevity here